# Delete ndb EntitiesByProperty index table

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an NDB model with some obsolete `EntitiesByProperty` indexes. Some belong to properties that are no longer part of the schema (but they do exist on some old entities), and some belong to properties that are never used for queries (but they were with `Indexed=True` because this is ndb model's default).

I tried using `vacuum_indexes`, but it only vacuums composite indexes.
I also changed some of those properties to have `Indexed=False`, but no `EntitiesByProperty` index tables are deleted.

How can I remove obsolete `EntitiesByProperty` index table? It looks like I'll have to write some code that will update all model entities. Is it correct? Are there any other ways of simply dropping the entire table?

Comment: datastore doesn't have tables.... do you mean "kinds"? or "index"?

Comment: I mean all indexes in EntitiesByProperty table where `kind=MyModel` and `property name=an_obsolete_property`

Comment: Are you talking about the sqlite db that the SDK uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to re-put all of your entities in order to update the values in the indexes (or remove them, as you're asking)